# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

Tags: android

I am very new to Java and Android Studio.

I am using this sample code

http://javapapers.com/android/draw-path-on-google-maps-android-api/

My project compiles and runs to the following point. I have tried debug mode and I can see the Google Map displays and the 3 markers are display. Then I get the following message.

```
9-03 00:06:04.459  19022-19022/nyc.mymaptest3 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: nyc.mymaptest3, PID: 19022
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
            at nyc.mymaptest3.PathGoogleMapActivity$ParserTask.onPostExecute(PathGoogleMapActivity.java:128)
            at nyc.mymaptest3.PathGoogleMapActivity$ParserTask.onPostExecute(PathGoogleMapActivity.java:101)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5938)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

I feel like the routes being returned are empty / null and I do not know how to debug this any further.

Line 101 starts here >>>

```
private class ParserTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(
                String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                PathJSONParser parser = new PathJSONParser();
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }
```

Line 128 shown below >>>

```
protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions polyLineOptions = null;

            // traversing through routes

            for (int i = 0; i < routes.size(); i++) {
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                polyLineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = routes.get(i);

Line 128            for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    points.add(position);
                }

                polyLineOptions.addAll(points);
                polyLineOptions.width(2);
                polyLineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
            }

            googleMap.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);
        }
```

Comment: Well it looks like routes isn't null which is good but you might want to look into why routes.get(i) for a specific i is null. The answer isn't here possibley in your parser.

Comment: @AndrewBrooke `routes` being `null` should break on first `for`. It probably isn't `null`, but the content is unexpected. Anyways, hard to tell without debugging.

Comment: Yep, I misread that. There might still be an error parsing the JSON however, you should check if its valid: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

After  this

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> path =    routes.get(i);
```

Add

```
If(path==null) break;
```